# Unable to delete an item from multiple collections in firebase

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have two collection in firebase, say A and B. When I add an item to one of the collections, say A, it automatically adds to another collection B. But when I delete an item from collection A, it remains in the other collection B.

[Shot from firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qSKG.jpg)

When I delete an item from collection A, it remains in the other collection B.

I am unable to figure out how to make the items deleted in both collections?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is no relational DB. Cascadate updates/deletes are possible in relational DBs like Sql, Postgresql, Firebird... In No-SQL You do not have any relations one document to another. What' more it is desirable to have some data cloned in two or more documents rather than creating a separate doc for it.

But maybe You can achieve what You want by using reference type? I sow it once or twice, it might be a good idea to check it out. But be the description it is only a field with path/reference, no magic [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

By the [official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> If you want to delete documents in subcollections when deleting a parent document, you must do so manually, as shown in Delete Collections.

So You either want to rethink The DB model or have to manualy track each wlement You want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that:

From client side use batch write ([more here](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-example-tab-))

```
DocumentReference doc_1_reference = firestore.collection("messages").document(doc_1_uid);
DocumentReference doc_2_reference = firestore.collection("messages").document(doc_2_uid);

final batchWrite = firestore.batch();

batchWrite.delete(doc_1_reference);
batchWrite.delete(doc_2_reference);

await batchWrite.commit();
```

Using Cloud functions by adding a delete trigger to the documents, and perform the deletion of the other document when triggered. Given you have away to know which document you're supposed to delete which is not difficult to do ([read about it here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events))

Comment: inside your application! Wherever you call the delete function. Please, check the links for examples and more information.